# Check existence of solution Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I have 2 functions that return 2 arrays T1 and T2, I want to calculate H=T1/T2 and if there is no solution {do something}. T1 is vector and T2 is Jacobian matrix. (I need to solve equation T2*d=T1)
I try

```
if isempty(T1\T2)
    {doing something}
end
```

But isempty function always returns 0. How can I check exestence of solution T1\T2?

In command window matlab says

```
Warning: System is inconsistent. Solution does not exist.
```

UPDATE: I try this

```
d=inv(H)*phi
```

It works, but what is the difference and how can I use command '\'?

Comment: First, are you sure you actually wanted `T2\T1` and not `T1\T2` (if `T2` is a matrix and `T1` a vector)? And what is `H`? Also, are you using symbolic math or numbers? In the second case, can you provide a sample input (values for `T1` and `T2`)? And have a look at the [condition number](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cond.html) of your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rank to judge if your system does not have a unique solution:

```
if rank([T2,d]) ~= rank(T2)
    {doing something}
end
```

Comment: I dont know value of d , I need to calculate it d=T1\T2 or if this system is unsolvable d=grad(F);